# Generating data on the server or client

Tags: javascript, php, performance, client-server

So for my current project I was wondering whether it is better to generate data, which should be displayed on the client, with js or on the server with php.

Some info about the data:

- There are two segments

  - the first one

    - needs to be rendered once when the side loads
    - static does not change dynamicly
  - the second one

    - needs to be rendered once when the side loads
    - does change about every hour or less
    - about 1/30 of the first segment
- both segments contain several items
- the displayed data is identical for every client
- those items are calculated out of two numbers for each item
- those calculations results in about three times the amount of data

Why I would like to do it server side:

- less loading time for the client
- less js, less errors
- better control of the result
- static data sheet (for both segments because the server would just render it if needed)

Why I would like to do it client side:

- less traffic
- more possibilities for the usage of the raw data

I hope someone could give me some advice, btw. I don't want to split the segments up and render the first server side and the second client side because the calculation is pretty much the same and that would mean to write the same script in php and js :/

I am not even sure if someone can help me with that because that is not really a problem but an performance decision.

Anyway thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: @RJ In version one I used the server side approach, It worked quite well, but the usage is kinda low so there is no actual reference. But at the moment I am working on the second version and I though of changing the way of generating the data and hoped to get some other opinions or points of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I concluded that I will use the client side approach.